# Conditional logistic regression with random effects - glmer with 'strata'?

Tags: matching, lme4-nlme

I have matched pairs of cases and controls and would like to perform a conditional logistic regression including random effects.

Is it possible to use the `strata` command like in the `clogit` function?

Would

```
glmer(Y ~ X + (1|Z) + strata(Pair), family=binomial("logit"))
```

give correct results?